# VBA Macro Sum Variable Range

Tags: vba, excel

I need to add up the total for column L, I know the first and last rows:

```
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
fRow = Cells(lRow, "B").Value
```

So how do I use `lRow` and `fRow` in my SUM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
activecell.Formula = "=SUM(L" & lrow & ":L" & frow & ")"
```

Edit - Added:

```
Sub Assign
  dim dbl_assign as long

  lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
  fRow = Cells(lRow, "B").Value

  activecell.Formula = "=SUM(L" & lrow & ":L" & frow & ")"

  dbl_assign = activecell.value

end sub
```

Comment: Thanks - how would I use that to assign the value retrieved by the formula to a variable in the VBA?